# Is anything known about Sokoban with only 1 box?

Tags: reductions, space-bounded, nondeterminism

This is intended to be a simpler version of [my earlier question here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31077/6973).
In this post, 1-Sokoban-search is [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) with only 1 box, 1-Sokoban-decision is
the [corresponding decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem), and 1-Sokoban refers to both of those problems.
(You get to choose whether that also means there's only one storage location or
still allows more storage locations. ​ Everything I say here applies in either case.)
1-Sokoban is trivially in NL. ​ Since, regardless of whether the ?s are X or blank, the region

```
?  X
X
XXX?
```

will have no box and no storage location and be such that the box can be pushed
from the top to exit out the right but can't be pushed from the right to the top, [(directed) Grid Graph Reachability](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/pub/allender/ggr.pdf) / (directed) GG search ​ ​ can easily be reduced to ​ 1-Sokoban-decision / 1-Sokoban-search ​ respectively,
so 1-Sokoban is [NC<sup>1</sup>](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#nc1)-hard and not known to be solvable by L.
Grid Graph distance is [known to be in ​ UL ∩ coUL](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.164.9920&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=7) , ​ so by any search-to-value
reduction, that is no *obstacle* to putting 1-Sokoban in ​ UL ∩ coUL .
(However, I don't have any evidence for 1-Sokoban being *in* even L<sup>[promis](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#promiseup)e[Few](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fewp)L</sup>.)

> #### Is anything else known about 1-Sokoban?

In particular, I have been unable to come up with any decision-to-search reduction in which the search oracle incorrectly reporting "no solution" never causes false negatives / search-to-decision reduction by any slightly-"natural" class, even with a GGsearch oracle, that can't obviously already solve all of ​ NL / [FN](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp)L ​respectively, and I've also been unable to come up with any
evidence for or against hardness of 1-Sokoban, beyond the reduction from Grid Graphs.

Comment: Please stop breaking lines inside a paragraph manually.